# Why is "RasterToOtherFormat" tool creating corrupted .TFW files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geotiff-tiff

Using the "RasterToOtherFormat" tool in ArcGIS 10.1 to convert *tiff's with .tfwx* file to *tiff's with .tfw* file, I get corrupt .twf files. That means, the saved coordinates in the new twf file are not correct and can't be read by QGIS.

Has this something to do with my ArcGIS Installation? If I run this tool from a different PC with ArcGIS 10.3 I get correct .tfw files. Is this a settings problem?

Comment: From what you describe it sounds like a bug in 10.1 that was fixed in 10.3, so suggest you keep using the 10.3 machine?

Comment: Well, the 10.3 machine is no longer accessible due to a moving fellow worker. I can only use the 10.1 ArcGIS Installation.

Comment: It looks like I found a solution: I determine a specific coordinate system (ETRS 89 UTM 32N) in the enviromental settings that apply to all tools. After i tried several "RasterToOtherFormat" run's, i got QGIS readable .twf's.